# Wrap wordpress post and title in custom div

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wrapper

I'm trying to prepare a blog for microformat, so I need a div to start above the title and close just above the social share buttons (and below meta data, date, author, # of views, etc) - see site for reference: http://www.sara-maria.dk/sundt/laekre-saltede-mandler-med-soedt-tilbehoer/

It is a Wordpress site using CherryFramework with a childtheme and I've tried the following:

1. adding the opening of the div to title.php and the closing div to footer.php

However, for some reason the div is not using the expected closing div. Instead it is being closed way up higher on the page.

2. I've created a new functions.php in the childtheme and used the following code:

   function my_content($content) {
   global $post;
   return ''.$content.'';
   }

   add_filter('the_content', 'my_content');

Problem is that this only wraps it around the post and my PHP skills are not very good, so I haven't been able to customize it to include the title and the meta data.

Anyone who can help me how I best can create the custom div?

Thanks,
Kasper

Update - copying in loop-single.php on request from dojs:

```
<?php /* Loop Name: Single */ ?>
<div id="loopTEST">
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    // The following determines what the post format is and shows the correct file accordingly
    $format = get_post_format();
    get_template_part( 'includes/post-formats/'.$format );
    if($format == '')
        get_template_part( 'includes/post-formats/standard' );
    get_template_part( 'includes/post-formats/share-buttons' );
    wp_link_pages('before=<div class="pagination">&after=</div>');
?>
</div>
<!---removed author block--->

<?php
    get_template_part( 'includes/post-formats/related-posts' );
    comments_template('', true);
    endwhile; endif; 
?>
```

Comment: You need to edit your template files. Find out where "The Loop" lies inside the file that prints your posts. Read more on [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)

Comment: Thanks, dojs! This was really helpful. I located the loop (in my case it was located in a folder named 'loop' and the file was named 'loop-single.php'). Problem is that the title still isn't part of the div when adding it. 
Post and meta data is part of the div, but not the title - any other suggestions?

Comment: Could you paste the code (loop-single.php) that prints your posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

If you look at the DOM of your site you can clearly see that the title section is found in it's own file.

Take a look at this HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span12" data-motopress-type="static" data-motopress-static-file="static/static-title.php">
    <section class="title-section">
    <h1 class="title-header">
        Lækre saltede mandler med sødt tilbehør </h1>
    <!-- BEGIN BREADCRUMBS-->
    ...
    <!-- END BREADCRUMBS -->
    </section><!-- .title-section -->
    </div>
</div>
```

You would think that you have to add a div to "static/static-title.php", but that would most likely destroy the layout.

To be honest, the structure of this theme seems horrible to me (which means that the theme is shit), however if you are hell bent on using it you need to find the file (which would most likely be "single.php" in your themes root directory) that includes "static/static-title.php" and add a div on the line above that.

---

Okay, well to really see how this builds up your single post pages you might need to go through the included template parts, but try this to start out with.

```
<div id="loopTEST">
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    $format = get_post_format();
?>
<div> <!-- This should be above the title -->
<?php
    get_template_part( 'includes/post-formats/'.$format );
    if($format == '')
        get_template_part( 'includes/post-formats/standard' );
?>
</div> <!-- This should be below the post but above the social media buttons -->
<?php
    get_template_part( 'includes/post-formats/share-buttons' );
    wp_link_pages('before=<div class="pagination">&after=</div>');
?>
</div>
```

Comment: The close of the div is spot on, but the title still isn't inside the div. You can have a look at the URL in my question. The id of the div is: newLoopTest

Comment: Well you are almost there, try adding a div on top of that line of code.

Comment: as mentioned I did that, and it only wraps it around the title.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read that, what about single.php in your themes root directory? There must be a file that includes both the static-title.php and loop-single.php.

Comment: dojs, you're a rockstar! That did it! Thank you so much for your help on this matter. As previously state I truly appreciate it.

Comment: Good job! Have a nice day